# css nth-child(3n+1) not working when 'another' element between childred

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My HTML code:

```
<div class="span4">1</div>
<div class="span4">2</div>
<div class="span4">3</div>
<div class="span12">banner</div>
<div class="span4">4</div>
<div class="span4">5</div>
<div class="span4">6</div>
<div class="span4">7</div>
<div class="span4">8</div>
<div class="span4">9</div>
```

Css:

```
.span4:nth-child(3n+1){
    color: red;
}
```

In result there must be 1, 4, 7 red colored. But it's not.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/473UR/
How to solve that problem?

Comment: The problem here is that there's no  nth-of-class selector. You'll need to use JS

Comment: Can you provide example please? Because jquery works in absolutely same way.

Answer (score 2):

`.nth-child` works with the consecutive element. If there is any other elements comes in between it starts calculating from the first.

```
<div class="span4">1</div>  <-- this is first-child -->
<div class="span4">2</div>
<div class="span4">3</div>
<div class="span12">banner</div>
<div class="span4">4</div>   <-- sequence reset.
<div class="span4">5</div>
<div class="span4">6</div>   
<div class="span4">7</div>
<div class="span4">8</div>
<div class="span4">9</div>
```

Comment: Any chance to solve that problem? I need to save span12 div in that place.

Answer (score 0):

That's because .span12 counts as a child too. If you remove it, it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your banner div and it will work

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/473UR/2/)

```
<div class="span4">1</div>
<div class="span4">2</div>
<div class="span4">3</div>
<div class="span4">4</div>
<div class="span4">5</div>
<div class="span4">6</div>
<div class="span4">7</div>
<div class="span4">8</div>
<div class="span4">9</div>
<div class="span12">banner</div>
```

Comment: I can't move this div in any other place.